# How would you add some "sports field lines" on Unity Terrain?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Imagine you have some Unity3D Terrain using their Terrain system.

So, imagine 3 or 4 acres of just brown dirt or white snow.

Imagine you want to add some markings, some painting on the Terrain - detail stuff.

A good example is those blue lines they use on ski runs:

[image]

How the heck would you add those blue lines to Terrain?

And unfortunately it needs to work in VR.

You could use projection I guess, or decals, but that's hokey.  Decals would be a pain unless flat surface (but maybe there's a technique for making "shape matching decals" or the like?  IDK)

Comment: Why would the surface need to be "flat" for decals?

Comment: hi @Eddge - ? well decals are of course flat.  if you sit a flat decal on a jiggly surface, it generally looks weird - give it a try.

Comment: not all decals are flat, there are several decal shaders out there that aren't flat.  Take a look at the free systems on the Unity Asset store several of those aren't flat.  There are also tutorials for "deferred Decals" which are basically just projections.  Any number of those would work.

Comment: "there are several decal shaders out there that aren't flat", hmm, that doesn' make sense to me, but I will definitely check on the store - and thanks!

Comment: now that I reread my statement it doesnt to me either, what I meant is there are several shaders out there that don't rely on a flat surface.

Comment: in any event thanks a million for the fantastic tip - why not type it in as an answer?  would help many

Comment: ahh .. I wonder if the deferred will work in VR ???  @Eddge

Comment: I don't have enough experience with VR systems(Very sadly I wish I did) to give a good concise response on it, I have read that deferred does work with some headsets, if not you could always generate a mesh that conforms to the terrain and use that as a "decal"  I haven't written it as an answer because I would like to make sure everything I am mentioning will work for your needs, and I have no machine to test it on currently.  When I get home I can write something up to generate a mesh to use as a decal if you'd like.

Comment: Decals are absolutely not required to be flat. They don't even have the requirement that they cover only one piece of geometry. Here's an example from a (really rather old) project of mine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKycC.jpg

Comment: you;'re quite right, @Draco18s .  I guess really the answer is "DECALS".   someone should put in an answer!

Comment: Curious what the answer to this would be today with URP and the need for long continuous lines like demonstrated here vs a small decal? Is it possible to take something like a Line Renderer and make it behave like a decal?

Comment: to be honest @todd I STILL don't have a great solution to this.  it's really annoying.  note that the conclusion above is, let us say, "decal-like shaders". I feel the bottom-line answer is it has to be done at the shader level, there's no getting around it.  Just like something amazing such as Splatoon (the painting) - it's shaders all teh way down

Comment: also @todd for anyone googling here, check out on asset store **Paintz** (amazing), also the famous VolumetricLines, and also Linefy and FastLineRenderer.  If I'm not mistaken I ended up, in fact using VolumetricLines. There's just no really great solution, oddly!

Comment: its very likely THIS LIBRARY is probably the best one as of 2021  https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/painting/paint-in-3d-26286

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## You're looking for decals

Not much to say on this, other than, yes, you want a decal system.

There *are* decal systems that can only render flat decals (and those do tend to be more performant) but that isn't the only way to do decals.

I've worked with [Simple Decal System](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/simple-decal-system-13889) before, it's what's running [the decal I used in my comment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKycC.jpg). I won't say it's a *great* system, but it is free. It is possible that [UV Paint](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/uvpaint-skinned-mesh-decal-system-61022) is better at $50, but I don't know.

Comment: Years later .. I would just say, the solution is "decal-like shaders".  But there's still no great solution for this.  I would say "decal" really just means a (old-school) decal, which is just a flat sticker.  (Of course that's just words, but there you go!)  The phrase "skinned mesh Decals" seems to have come along, maybe that's the best terminology!!